# ExportToHttpResponse is not responding after using try catch in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

ExportToHttpResponse is giving error: “Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.” 
After using Try Catch it is working Fine in debug ... but after published in IIS it is giving error without try catch and if i use try catch it doesnt respond.. pdf file doesnt download. nothing happens.. 
I need help...

```
protected void Link4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    crystalReport = obj.CRDirectory(Server.MapPath(@"CrystalReport\MembersDirectory.rpt"));
    Response.Buffer = false;
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    try 
    {                 
        crystalReport.ExportToHttpResponse(
          ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat,      
          Response, true, "MembersDirectory"); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }       
}`
```

I searched a lot on internet but i did not find anything that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try This way.

```
ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();    
crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("MembersDirectory.rpt"));
Response.Buffer = false;
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
 try
 {
        crystalReport.ExportToHttpResponse(
          ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat,
          Response, true, "MembersDirectory");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {

    }
```

Comment: crystalReport object is defined above the event... the problem is in ExportToHttpResponse... not in crystal report object.

Comment: Yahya  your code works on my machine, i think there is path issue , have you tried using crystalReport.load method for loading report?